# google cloud - kubectl - ingress - "default backend - 404"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a google cloud kubernetes cluster, 
service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-05-14T18:53:57Z
  labels:
    run: sv-security
  name: sv-security
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "554"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/sv-security
  uid: 27e476db-57a8-11e8-9053-42010a84014c
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.47.245.44
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32290
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: sv-security
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.205.38.34
```

and I would like to have HTTPS enabled.
I followed some tutorials and got the following ingress config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-sv-security
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: sv-security
    servicePort: 80
```

(tried with serivce port 32290 as well).
And created it with "kubectl apply -f ingress-sv-security.yaml"

When I go to the ip address, I get "default backend - 404".

When I run "kubectl describe ing", I get:

```
Name:             ingress-sv-security
Namespace:        default
Address:          35.201.113.164
Default backend:  sv-security:32290 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     *     sv-security:32290 (<none>)
Annotations:
  url-map:          k8s-um-default-ingress-sv-security--d01e081d01fdd251
  backends:         {"k8s-be-32062--d01e081d01fdd251":"HEALTHY"}
  forwarding-rule:  k8s-fw-default-ingress-sv-security--d01e081d01fdd251
  target-proxy:     k8s-tp-default-ingress-sv-security--d01e081d01fdd251
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age               From                     Message
  ----     ------   ----              ----                     -------
  Normal   ADD      19m               loadbalancer-controller  default/ingress-sv-security
  Normal   CREATE   18m               loadbalancer-controller  ip: 35.201.113.164
  Warning  Service  0s (x8 over 18m)  loadbalancer-controller  failed to identify user specified default backend, couldn't find nodeport for default/sv-security, using system default
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: where is your secret? when you describe your service, do you have any endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Ingress with no rules, sends all traffic to a single default backend.
See here for the [Prerequisites](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing/glbc#prerequisites)

For encrypted communication between the client to the load balancer, you need to specify a TLS private key and certificate to be used by the ingress controller. see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce#frontend-https)